# location different CGPoint

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

Hi
how do I locate both the cgpoint? he gives me just one.

```
-(void)gestureLoad {

//GESTURE

UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer;


recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(numTap2:)];
[(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
self.tapRecognizer = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
recognizer.delegate = self;
[recognizer release];
}

- (void)numTap2:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {


CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];


...other actions...
}
```

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description of -[UIGestureRecognizer numberOfTouches]:

> Using the value returned by this
>   method in a loop, you can ask for the
>   location of individual touches using
>   the locationOfTouch:inView: method.

So, call -locationOfTouche:inView: for each touch to get the corresponding location.

Comment: thanks for the reply
I tried to use it, but I did not quite clear how to use it

    - (CGPoint)locationOfTouch:(NSUInteger)touchIndex inView:(UIView *)view {
 
 ....
 
}